# Why is std::vector<bool> faster?

Tags: c++, performance, stdvector

As I was implementing the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* I ran into an issue with `std::vector<bool>` : there is no access to the raw data.

So I decided to use a custom minimalistic implementation where I would have access to the data pointer.

```
#ifndef LIB_BITS_T_H
#define LIB_BITS_T_H

#include <algorithm>
template <typename B>

class bits_t{

public:

    typedef B block_t;
    static const size_t block_size = sizeof(block_t) * 8;

    block_t* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t blocks;

    class bit_ref{
    public:
        block_t* const block;
        const block_t mask;

        bit_ref(block_t& block, const block_t mask) noexcept : block(&block), mask(mask){}

        inline void operator=(bool v) const noexcept{
            if(v) *block |= mask;
            else  *block &= ~mask;
        }

        inline operator bool() const noexcept{
            return (bool)(*block & mask);
        }
    };



    bits_t() noexcept : data(nullptr){}

    void resize(const size_t n, const bool v) noexcept{
        block_t fill = v ? ~block_t(0) : block_t(0);
        size = n;
        blocks = (n + block_size - 1) / block_size;
        data = new block_t[blocks];
        std::fill(data, data + blocks, fill);
    }

    inline block_t& block_at_index(const size_t i) const noexcept{
        return data[i / block_size];
    }

    inline size_t index_in_block(const size_t i) const noexcept{
        return i % block_size;
    }

    inline bit_ref operator[](const size_t i) noexcept{
        return bit_ref(block_at_index(i), block_t(1) << index_in_block(i));
    }

    ~bits_t(){
        delete[] data;
    }

};

#endif // LIB_BITS_T_H
```

The code is nearly the same than the one in /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_bvector.h but is slower.

I tried an optimization,

```
#ifndef LIB_BITS_T_H
#define LIB_BITS_T_H

#include <algorithm>
template <typename B>

class bits_t{

const B mask[64] = {
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
};

public:

    typedef B block_t;
    static const size_t block_size = sizeof(block_t) * 8;

    block_t* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t blocks;

    class bit_ref{
    public:
        block_t* const block;
        const block_t mask;

        bit_ref(block_t& block, const block_t mask) noexcept : block(&block), mask(mask){}

        inline void operator=(bool v) const noexcept{
            if(v) *block |= mask;
            else  *block &= ~mask;
        }

        inline operator bool() const noexcept{
            return (bool)(*block & mask);
        }
    };



    bits_t() noexcept : data(nullptr){}

    void resize(const size_t n, const bool v) noexcept{
        block_t fill = v ? ~block_t(0) : block_t(0);
        size = n;
        blocks = (n + block_size - 1) / block_size;
        data = new block_t[blocks];
        std::fill(data, data + blocks, fill);
    }

    inline block_t& block_at_index(const size_t i) const noexcept{
        return data[i / block_size];
    }

    inline size_t index_in_block(const size_t i) const noexcept{
        return i % block_size;
    }

    inline bit_ref operator[](const size_t i) noexcept{
        return bit_ref(block_at_index(i), mask[index_in_block(i)]);
    }

    ~bits_t(){
        delete[] data;
    }

};

#endif // LIB_BITS_T_H
```

(Compiling with g++4.7 -O3)

**Eratosthenes sieve algorithm (33.333.333 bits)**

`std::vector<bool>` 19.1s

`bits_t<size_t>` 19.9s

`bits_t<size_t> (with lookup table)` 19.7s

**ctor + resize(33.333.333 bits) + dtor**

`std::vector<bool>` 120ms

`bits_t<size_t>` 150ms

***QUESTION*** : Where does the slowdown come from?

Comment: "_The code is **nearly** the same than the one in /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_bvector.h_"

Comment: Presumably the compiler is allowed to use the fact that `stl_bvector.h` is part of the implementation, allowing it to make special optimizations.

Comment: `resize` is a bit scary - it doesn't preserve the old data, and leaks the old allocation. You've also got invalid copy semantics.

Comment: Nearly meaning I didn't find anything different..

Comment: @Seymour It was just for one use case, I change it if I reuse it.

Comment: You code only 3% percent slower, I assume that the best way to get an answer is to take a profiler and study what happens, because one should be extra-pro to catch the difference just looking at the code.

Comment: A difference this small can be due to totally unrelated external factors such as how a hot loop aligns with code cache line boundaries.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Why do you think `resize()` leaks something?

Comment: @DarkWanderer: because it reassigns 'data' to a newly allocated lump of memory without deleting the old one.

Comment: @Mike: you are wrong. No STL container operations lead to memory leak. Proof, please.

Comment: @DarkWanderer: What are you talking about? There are no STL containers here (even if you interpret "STL" to mean "the standard library", which I assume you meant). `resize()` quite clearly allocates memory with `data = new block_t[blocks];` without deleting whatever `data` pointed to before. Calling it a second time will leak the first allocation.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, sorry, got you now. I've misunderstood the OP's implementation and consequently your comment. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the wrapping of `i % block_size` in a function was the culprit

```
inline size_t index_in_block ( const size_t i ) const noexcept {
    return i % block_size;
}

inline bit_ref operator[] ( const size_t i ) noexcept {
    return bit_ref( block_at_index( i ), block_t( 1 ) << index_in_block( i ) );
}
```

so replacing the above code with

```
inline bit_ref operator[] ( const size_t i ) noexcept {
    return bit_ref( block_at_index( i ), block_t( 1 ) << ( i % block_size ) );
}
```

solves the issue. However, I still don't know why it is. My best guess is that I didn't get the signature of index_in_block right and that the optimizer is thus not able to inline this function in a similar way to the *manual inlining* way.

Here is the new code.

```
#ifndef LIB_BITS_2_T_H
#define LIB_BITS_2_T_H

#include <algorithm>

template <typename B>

class bits_2_t {

public:

    typedef B block_t;
    static const int block_size = sizeof( block_t ) * __CHAR_BIT__;


private:

    block_t* _data;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _blocks;


public:

    class bit_ref {

    public:

        block_t* const block;
        const block_t mask;


        bit_ref ( block_t& block, const block_t mask) noexcept
        : block( &block ), mask( mask ) {}


        inline bool operator= ( const bool v ) const noexcept {

            if ( v ) *block |= mask;
            else     *block &= ~mask;

            return v;

        }

        inline operator bool() const noexcept {
            return (bool)( *block & mask );
        }


    };


    bits_2_t () noexcept : _data( nullptr ), _size( 0 ), _blocks( 0 ) {}

    bits_2_t ( const size_t n ) noexcept : _data( nullptr ), _size( n ) {

        _blocks = number_of_blocks_needed( n );
        _data = new block_t[_blocks];

        const block_t fill( 0 );
        std::fill( _data, _data + _blocks, fill );

    }

    bits_2_t ( const size_t n, const bool v ) noexcept : _data( nullptr ), _size( n ) {

        _blocks = number_of_blocks_needed( n );
        _data = new block_t[_blocks];

        const block_t fill = v ? ~block_t( 0 ) : block_t( 0 );
        std::fill( _data, _data + _blocks, fill );

    }

    void resize ( const size_t n ) noexcept {
        resize( n, false );
    }

    void resize ( const size_t n, const bool v ) noexcept {

        const size_t tmpblocks = number_of_blocks_needed( n );
        const size_t copysize = std::min( _blocks, tmpblocks );

        block_t* tmpdata = new block_t[tmpblocks];
        std::copy( _data, _data + copysize, tmpdata );

        const block_t fill = v ? ~block_t( 0 ) : block_t( 0 );
        std::fill( tmpdata + copysize, tmpdata + tmpblocks, fill );

        delete[] _data;

        _data = tmpdata;
        _blocks = tmpblocks;
        _size = n;

    }

    inline size_t number_of_blocks_needed ( const size_t n ) const noexcept {
        return ( n + block_size - 1 ) / block_size;
    }

    inline block_t& block_at_index ( const size_t i ) const noexcept {
        return _data[i / block_size];
    }

    inline bit_ref operator[] ( const size_t i ) noexcept {
        return bit_ref( block_at_index( i ), block_t( 1 ) << ( i % block_size ) );
    }

    inline bool operator[] ( const size_t i ) const noexcept {
        return (bool)( block_at_index( i ) & ( block_t( 1 ) << ( i % block_size ) ) );
    }

    inline block_t* data () {
        return _data;
    }

    inline const block_t* data () const {
        return _data;
    }

    inline size_t size () const {
        return _size;
    }

    void clear () noexcept {

        delete[] _data;

        _size = 0;
        _blocks = 0;
        _data = nullptr;

    }

    ~bits_2_t () {
        clear();
    }


};

#endif // LIB_BITS_2_T_H
```

Here are the results for this new code on my amd64 machine for primes up to `1.000.000.000` (best of 3 runs, real time).

*Sieve of Eratosthenes with 1 memory unit per number ( not skipping multiples of 2 ).*

bits_t<uint8_t>

real    0m23.614s user  0m23.493s sys   0m0.092s

bits_t<uint16_t>

real    0m24.399s user  0m24.294s sys   0m0.084s

bits_t<uint32_t>

**real  0m23.501s user  0m23.372s sys   0m0.108s** ***<-- best***

bits_t<uint64_t>

real    0m24.393s user  0m24.304s sys   0m0.068s

std::vector<bool>

real    0m24.362s user  0m24.276s sys   0m0.056s

std::vector<uint8_t>

real    0m38.303s user  0m37.570s sys   0m0.683s

Here is the code of the sieve (where `(...)` should be replaced by the bit array of your choice).

```
#include <iostream>

typedef (...) array_t;

int main ( int argc, char const *argv[] ) {

    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        std::cout << "#0 missing" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const size_t count = std::stoull( argv[1] );
    array_t prime( count, true );
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;


    for ( size_t k = 2 ; k * k < count ; ++k ) {

        if ( prime[k] ) {

            for ( size_t i = k * k ; i < count ; i += k ) {
                prime[i] = false;
            }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Outside of all the problems as pointed out by some other users, your resize is allocating more memory each time the current block limit is reached to add ONE block. The std::vector will double the size of the buffer (so if you already had 16 blocks, now you have 32 blocks). In other words, they will do less new than you.

This being said, you do not do the necessary delete & copy and that could have a "positive" impact in your version... ("positive" impact speed wise, it is not positive that you do not delete the old data, nor copy it in your new buffer.)

Also, the std::vector will properly enlarge the buffer and thus copy data that is likely already in your CPU cache. With your version, that cache is lost since you just ignore the old buffer on each resize().

Also when a class handles a memory buffer it is customary to implement the copy and assignment operators, for some reasons... and you could look into using a shared_ptr<>() too. The delete is then hidden and the class is a template so it is very fast (it does not add any code that you would not already have in your own version.)

=== Update

There is one other thing. You're `operator []` implementation:

```
inline bit_ref operator[](const size_t i) noexcept{
    return bit_ref(block_at_index(i), mask[index_in_block(i)]);
}
```

(side note: the inline is not required since the fact that you write the code within the class already means you okayed the inline capability already.)

You only offer a non-const version which "is slow" because it creates a sub-class. You should try implementing a const version that returns bool and see whether that accounts for the ~3% difference you see.

```
bool operator[](const size_t i) const noexcept
{
    return (block_at_index(i) & mask[index_in_block(i)]) != 0;
}
```

Also, using a `mask[]` array can also slow down things. (1LL << (index & 0x3F)) should be faster (2 CPU instructions with 0 memory access).

Comment: It's just named resize so I can switch between vector and this class... I really just do one resize during the whole execution.
shared_ptr uses polymorphism for the deleter so it is not exactly the same..

Comment: For the resize(), it is not clear how you use it. But it should probably be a set_size() instead, and the function could check, if the data is already defined, throw a runtime_error exception... just in case.

Comment: I will try your ideas about the [] operator. Maybe this one is also in the standard c++ library, perhaps I missed it. I'll tell you if it makes any difference for my use case. BTW in the question there is already a version without a lookup table using `block_t(1) << index_in_block(i)`. Why do you need a `0x3F` mask here?

Comment: Habit I guess... If your index is always within the range of the block data type, it is not needed. If your index can grow very large, then you need to make sure it repeats every 32 (0x1F) or 64 (0x3F) bits, depending on the type returned by block_at_index(). In your case, since that block_t is a template argument, that value should be calculated using that argument size (something like `sizeof(B) * 8 - 1`.) If you prefer a modulo: `i % (sizeof(B) * 8)`.

Comment: Also instead of 8 you can use `CHAR_BIT` which in most cases is 8 (a few processors have 16 bit bytes...)

Comment: Ah I see, instead of the modulo.. There is already a `static const size_t block_size = sizeof(block_t) * 8;` statement. Modulo of a (static) power of two should be 'optimized' to a `&` (if there's any difference in speed) but I'll try both.

Comment: Not (static).. meant (const)

Comment: Yes, the modulo of an integer can be optimized to `&` by the compiler. Speed wise, it can be huge if you do that in a loop since you avoid a division.

Comment: I've tested all your suggestions but apparently the compiler with the -O3 flag already does that himself. Hopefully I think I've found the culprit. Explicitly inlining `inline size_t index_in_block(const size_t i) const` (i.e. replacing the calls to the method with `i % block_size`) will give the same running time for `bits_t<unsigned long>` and `std::vector<bool>` but I'm not sure why it does.. Do you have an idea? I could share the code if you want to test it.

Comment: It could be that with inline the compiler obliges whereas without it, it may keep the function separate, even with -O3. That would not add much in terms of execution because it would certainly all be in the instruction cache. Since both are templates, though, I thought pretty much everything was inlined automatically. But I may be wrong on that one. A function considered too complex may not get inlined by default.

Comment: You should dump out the assembly code and see exactly what the difference is between the two cases. With a handful of bash instructions you can dump out the assembly in both cases and diff, will probably tell you the answer in a matter of moments without guessing.